# Most efficient way to store and retrieve a map data in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, multidimensional-array

here's the thing, i need to store different values in a 2d array (or something conceptually similar). The idea is to create a 2d map with tiles and the array would save the ID of every tile in the map. I'm trying to create something mildly efficient, specially because i need to save some memory usage for later use (it has to do with AI) and it must run on a low end PC, but simply creating an array seems to be a waste of space since i only have about 50 different IDs at any given map.

i thought about creating a 2d array of 8bit chars would be sufficient, but that's out of the question with actionscript 3, it doesn't have 8bit char data type. Could i use vectors with strings or something? So I'm asking you, what would the most efficient way be?

Comment: My advice: dont pre-optmize. Write it, within reason, to work and then profile it to see where your bottlenecks actually are. If it were me, I'd use a fixed sized `Vector.<uint>` until profiling told me that wasn't fast enough. Any optimization before that is just guessing.

Comment: +1 to what 32bitkid said. A fixed sized vector most likely going to be your fastest option. You also have the option of using a ByteArray that would give you more control. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html

Comment: ByteArray seems to be what i was looking for, just not sure if it's actually fast enough for me. I'll take your advice 32bitkid, for now i have it working with a simple 2d array, but i'll keep bytearray and vectors in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the way to go is to use ByteArray - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html. You can read and write one or more bytes at a time. You can even use the compress function to reduce its size (it actually "zips" it)

You should "flatten" the map into the byte array i.e map[i][j] will be stored in byteArray[i*nr_columns + j]